# React Native Linking to facebook profile only opens current user's profile instead of given URL

Tags: react-native, facebook, deep-linking, react-native-linking

I have the following code:

```
Linking.openURL(`fb://profile/?app_scoped_user_id=${user}`)
```

`user` is taken from the url of the person's profile, so in the url `https://facebook.com/ian`, user would be `ian`.

No matter who the user is, the facebook app always opens to the profile page of whoever is logged into facebook, not the user as listed in the url.

How do I link to a user's facebook profile in the facebook app from a React Native app?

Comment: app_scoped_user_id has to be an app_scoped_user_id. You can pass in random user names.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass in the userId not the user name to link to the users profile

`fb://profile/userid`